# Permissions issues when querying a table created from Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a Big Query table using a Google Sheet as a source.

I am trying to query the table with some Python script.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport import requests

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    r"[key location]")

project_id = '[PROJECT]'

client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)


query_job = client.query("""
  SELECT *
  FROM [TABLENAME]
  LIMIT 10""")
results = query_job.result()
```

However, I am receiving the following error.

```
Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.
```

I have successfully used the above code to query another table (not from a Sheet source), so the issue is specifically to do with the table sourced from Sheets. I have tried running the code both on a cloud resource (using a service account) and locally.

Does anyone know the fix?

Comment: most likely your credentials are wrong, or the credentials have limited access. make sure the IP that running the code is allowed to access the table.

Answer (score 0):

You must **enable drive access** of BigQuery by using the code from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-drive#enable-google-drive) to create credentials for both BigQuery and Google Drive. Please do note that both **BigQuery API** and **Google Drive API** must be enabled before running the code.

I updated the code from your question and used it on my testing as shown below:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
import google.auth


# Create credentials with Drive & BigQuery API scopes.
# Both APIs must be enabled for your project before running this code.
credentials, project = google.auth.default(
    scopes=[
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery",
    ]
)

project_id = '[PROJECT]'

client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)

query_job = client.query("""
  SELECT *
  FROM [TABLENAME]
  LIMIT 10""")
results = query_job.result()

#Printing results for my testing
for row in results:
    row1 = row['string_field_0']
    row2 = row['string_field_1']
    print(f'{row1} | {row2}')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: "enable drive access of BigQuery"

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: By removing the service account credential on your code and change it to the one I provided on my posted answer (line7 to 12 of my provided sample code). You may use my updated code for your testing.  Be sure to enable Google Drive API first since I assume that BigQuery API is already enabled to your project

Comment: I can't get the code to work. Further, I have tried creating an empty table and a scheduled query to overwrite the table. I figured this could be a way of bypassing the need to directly query the table. However, I am getting a 'scheduled query error'. 

I'm pretty sure this is a permission error. I have played around in IAM and added loads of new roles, but nothing works. I'm lost.

Comment: Can you share the error message you got when you tried the code from my answer?

Comment: Find the error below. This is from running your exact code, with the only changes being that I've added speadsheets and cloud-platform to scope. I can query other BQ tables that are not sourced from Sheets fine using this script.


`Forbidden: 403 Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials.

Location: US
Job ID: 130c5e8c-1a4c-4398-9d75-d25169f91abd`

Comment: Can you try to just use the exact code without changing the scopes?